# Notation confusing my understanding of a homework problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Probably ultra simple, but asking google about notation is non-trivial in a case like this.  The text is Oksendal's Stochastic Diff Eq and, very simply, the question is as follows:

> Let $B_t$ denote n-dimensional Brownian motion and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^2$.  Use Ito's formula to prove that
>   $$f(B_t) = f(B_0) + \int_0^t \nabla f(B_s) dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \Delta f(B_s) ds$$
>   where $\Delta = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$ is the Laplace operator.

Never took real analysis so tough for me to understand how a function mapping $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can have anything to do with two-dimensional complex space?  Is this a purely notational misunderstanding?

Assuming I sort of ignore my misunderstanding, it should be as simple as integrating both sides of one-dimensional Ito's, no?

Comment: $ C^2$ means twice differentiable, not complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{C}^2$ or $\mathbf{C}^2$ denotes the complex $2$-dimensional space. In this context, $C^2$ means twice-differentiable. In general, a $C^n$ function is differentiable $n$ times.